# Is there a difference between u and c in mknod

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, devices, character-special-files

From `man mknod` on Linux:

```
 c, u   create a character (unbuffered) special file
```

Why are there 2 letters for the same function? Is there any subtle difference, or they are completely alike?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're identical, at least on Linux.

I came to this conclusion by first looking at the [source code for `mknod(1)`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/mknod.c) in the [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html), where on line 217 in the current version we find that the `'c'` and `'u'` cases are treated identically, getting the same device type. The `S_IFCHR` value is defined in the Linux kernel headers, but the value is not important. All that matters is that the same value gets stored in the filesystem's dev node.

I clinched the issue with a simple test:

```
$ sudo mknod /dev/null2 u 1 3
$ ls -l /dev/null*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Jan 12  2015 /dev/null
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 1, 3 Oct 19 22:56 /dev/null2
```

A `u` in the command gives the same dev node as `c`. Case closed.

As to *why* both characters are allowed, my best guess is that it's just an alias for those who think of `b` as meaning "buffered" rather than "block," so that you need `u` as its opposite, meaning "unbuffered," rather than `c` for "character."

I originally thought that this feature of GNU `mknod` might have been for compatibility with some pre-Linux flavor of Unix, since `mknod` in [GNU Fileutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities#History) predates Linux itself,¹ and this feature of GNU `mknod` goes clear back to [the very first version-controlled checkin of `mknod.c`](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/coreutils/coreutils/src/mknod.c?revision=1.1&view=markup), but I have yet to find documentation for any Unix that will accept `u` as an argument to `mknod(1)`, so that hypothesis doesn't hold water.²

---

**Asides:**

1. A `mknod` utility was added to GNU Fileutils in July 1991. The first version of the Linux kernel wasn't posted to Usenet until September 1991. That tells us that the first version of GNU `mknod` must have supported non-Linux OSes from the start.
2. I've checked the online man pages for [Solaris](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54764/mknod-1m.html), [HP-UX](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/mknod.1m.html), [AIX](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/mknod.htm), [FreeBSD](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/8/mknod/), [SCO OpenServer](http://osr507doc.xinuos.com/en/man/html.C/mknod.C.html), [SCO UnixWare](http://uw714doc.xinuos.com/en/man/html.1M/mknod.1M.html), [Minix 2](https://www.minix-vmd.org/cgi-bin/man?/usr/man+8+mknod), [Ultrix](http://www.unix.com/man-page/ultrix/8/mknod/), [2.11BSD](http://www.unix.com/man-page/bsd/8/mknod/), and [OS X](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mknod.8.html).

   You will find `mknod u` documented for other OSes — such as [Minix 3](http://man.minix3.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=mknod) — but only because they're also using the GNU Coreutils implementation of `mknod(1)`. Another oddity is modern Solaris, which ships both AT&T `mknod` and GNU `mknod`, documented separately in manual sections 1m (linked above) and in section 1g, respectively.

Comment: It makes perfect sense that the GNU utilities would have supported some non-Linux kernel, because GNU started (in 1984) by writing free replacements for various UNIX utilities to run on UNIX systems. When Torvalds released the Linux kernel, that just added one large missing piece towards making a full operating system unencumbered by UNIX "intellectual property". In fact, today, there's GNU Hurd. You may want to compare [my answer to *Were all Unix commands re-written in Linux?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85196/2465) which has more of the relevant history than can fit in a comment.

Comment: For the record, it's not documented in current manpages available online for HP-UX, AIX, Ultrix, or SCO Unix (which supports several other file types in mknod), either, and it's not present in any version of Minix that I found source code for.