# What is a "weird file"?

Tags: filesystems, stat

An application I am using will not start with this user message: `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/sleblanc/.config/app/.config`

When I used `ls`, the file showed up as such:

```
?--------- 1 root root     0 Dec 31  1969 .config
```

Running stat on the file gives me this:

```
% stat .config
  File: .config
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   weird file
Device: 2dh/45d Inode: 9799944     Links: 1
Access: (0666/?rw-rw-rw-)  Uid: ( 1000/     sleblanc)   Gid: ( 1000/         sleblanc)
Access: 1969-12-31 19:00:00.000000000 -0500
Modify: 1969-12-31 19:00:00.000000000 -0500
Change: 2018-04-07 23:40:22.549653691 -0400
```

Most surprising is this mention of a "weird file".

What is a weird file?

Comment: What does `stat -c '%f' .config` print?  (You should get a four-digit hexadecimal number.)  Also, what does `stat -f .config` print?  (This reports information about the filesystem containing `.config`.)

Comment: The file has owner/group of root, which is ID zero. This supports @peterh's supposition that some of the the metadata has been zeroed.

Comment: Are you using eCryptfs?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

(Assuming GNU...) If `stat` couldn't tell what type it is (directory, (empty) regular file, link,
socket, ...), it says [`weird file`](//github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/d9afeac/lib/file-type.c#L110). I’d guess filesystem
corruption and suggest `fsck`.

---

[In 2014](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/commit/47f93b076d2083144591dcb7deedbda450085379), additional recognized file types were added to GNU coreutils. So, if your version is older than that, it may well be a reasonable file for some special circumstance, but an app is highly likely to store its config in a regular file.

Comment: However, some software might use a socket or link of some odd type named .config ...

Comment: @rackandboneman `stat` from GNU coreutils on my system happily reports a socket as a `socket`. Symlinks are reported as `symbolic link`. Hardlinks are indistinguishable from "regular" files and are reported as `regular file` (that's what they are, after all), except that the links count is >1.

Comment: "of some odd type" - I was referring to the other dozens of sockety or linky types found in that super-verbose section of C code  (there certainly is a good reason for not just indexing an array of strings with the file type number ... I guess...) :)

Comment: @rackandboneman Base POSIX doesn't provide any way to extract a "file type number" from a stat structure, only the S_ISxxx() macros.  Some Unixes offer a set of "XSI" extensions that include a way to do that, but coreutils tries not to depend on XSI, or did the last time I looked anyway.

Comment: Ahhh OK. I was kind of mis-assuming coreutils to be more GNU/linux centric that it is meant to be :)

Comment: @rackandboneman Linux came after GNU, and I suspect coreutils was one of the earlier parts of GNU. See e.g. [Were all Unix commands re-written in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85189/2465) (Full disclosure: My answer on that question.)