# Does Apple modify the GNU and BSD tools that comes with macOS?

Tags: osx, gnu, bsd

macOS comes with `bash` (which is a GNU tool), macOS also comes with tools like `ls` and `chmod` (which are BSD tools, even though I don't know from which BSD flavor they come from).

Now does the GNU and BSD tools that comes with macOS gets modified by Apple (for example: does Apple remove some features from them or add some features to them), or does Apple leave them unmodified?

Comment: Already answered at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506429/5132 .

Answer (score 5):

Yes Apple modifies at most open tools that come with MacOS in order to support Apple specific features.

You can see this in the man pages

https://ss64.com/osx/

or if you diff the source

https://opensource.apple.com/

As a specific example compare these 3 links for ls.c;

https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/bin/ls/ls.c

https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-272/ls/ls.c.auto.html

https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/ls.c

Comment: Do you know of an example of a tool that come with macOS that Apple modified in order to support some Apple specific feature?

Comment: But **`ls`** is not listed [here](https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-10141.html) -

Comment: @ThomasDickey you may notice from the URL that "ls" is in the file_cmds repository.